# Autologin and autorun script only once for a user

Tags: boot

**Goal:**
  - boot the rpi and for it to play an mp3 continuously

**What I did:**
  - I autologin by editing `/etc/inittab` in the normal way
  - I run my commands by editing `~/.bash_profile` and adding `mpg321 mymusic.mp3`

**The problem**: the rpi boots, logs in the user, and plays the mp3. All good. But when I log in again via ssh, it runs the script again which plays the mp3 again, etc. *I only want it to do that once.*

I know I can have two users for this scenario, but I want to keep it simple and use one. Please help me do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to use cron to schedule the task instead.

Open the cron task list in the default text editor:

```
crontab -e
```

Add a line at the bottom to run the task after a reboot:

```
@reboot mpg321 mymusic.mp3
```

Save the file and exit the text editor.

cron should now run the command line once at reboot as root.
Note you may need to use an absolute path to `mymusic.mp3`, e.g. `/home/pi/mymusic.mp3`

Comment: Works well, and only once! If I want to stop this task BTW, how do I do it while I'm logged in via ssh?

Comment: @mrpi The easiest way would probably be to run `sudo killall mpg321`

Answer (score 0):

You could use "who" to know if you are already logged in:

```
if [ `who | grep "$LOGNAME" | wc -l` -eq 0 ]
then
    mpg321 mymusic.mp3
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in an if statement to check to see whether mpg321 is already running. There are a whole bunch of ways to do this. First way that comes to mind is this -
`pidof mpg321 | wc -l`